# how to control charset of directory listing via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, encoding, utf-8, cjk

I've enabled directory listing of a folder under public_html, by adding:

Options +Indexes

in the .htaccess file.

However, some files are not listed correctly by default, as some filenames are in Chinese (UTF-8 encoded). I can see the filenames if the change the browser's charset encoding to UTF-8.

How can I let the browser see the filenames in UTF-8 by default? Is there a parameter to add in the .htaccess? I tried adding:

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

in the .htaccess file but it does not change anything.

Thanks~

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IndexOptions Charset=UTF-8